# Is there a way to get hold of a common cluster time from Gemfire?

Tags: java, gemfire

Hazelcast offers a method on a Cluster instance, which returns a long that represents a common time across the cluster. From the [API doc](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/Cluster.html#getClusterTime%28%29):

> long getClusterTime()
>
> Returns the cluster-wide time in milliseconds.
>
> Cluster tries to keep a cluster-wide time which is might be different
>   than the member's own system time. Cluster-wide time is -almost- the
>   same on all members of the cluster.

Is there a similar function available on Gemfire?

Answer (score 0):

GemFire does not have a public API for accessing the cluster time. While the GemFire cluster does keep its own time it is not generally available. You should always configure your cluster of hosts to synchronize time, see NTP. Keeping your host times in sync will make your system time and cluster time offset very small and should remove the need to access the cluster time.